# A line perpendicular to a tangent curved at both ends

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, reference-request, curves, combinatorial-geometry

I made a guess two years ago. I have a strong feeling that there is a proof using the fixed point theorem with geometric visualization, but I couldn't do the proof.

If you have a simple closed convex curve, thr line Perpendicular to the tangent on the curve at both ends must be present

If this feature is already known, please point to a reference that mentions it

If you can prove it would be appreciated, thanks

[image]

Comment: A convex polygon with no parallel sides?

Comment: It is curved, not polygon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood your question, the following fact (which should be well-known) provides a positive answer to it.
Let $I$ be the unit segment $[0,1]$ endowed with the usual topology. Let $\varphi:I\to \mathbb R^2$ be a closed curve, that is a continuous map such that $\varphi(0)=\varphi(1)$. For each $(t_1,t_2)\in I^2$ put $f(t_1,t_2)$ equal to the inner product $(\varphi(t_1)-\varphi(t_2),\varphi(t_1)-\varphi(t_2))$, that is to the squared distance between the points $\varphi(t_1)$ and $\varphi(t_2)$. Then the function $f$ is continuous, being a composition of continuous functions. Since the set $I^2$ is compact, the function $f$ attains its maximum at some point $(s_1,s_2)\in I^2$. Suppose that for some $i\in\{1,2\}$ the function $\varphi$ is differentiable at the point $s_i$ and $\varphi'(s_i)\ne 0$ (in the case $s_i=0$ or $s_i=1$ we additionally require that $\varphi'(0)=\varphi'(1)$). Then
$$0=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t_i}{\huge|}_{s_i}=2(\varphi'(s_i),\varphi(s_i))-2(\varphi'(s_i),\varphi(s_{3-i}))=
2(\varphi'(s_i),\varphi(s_i)-\varphi(s_{3-i})),$$
which means that the vector $\varphi'(s_i)$ is perpendicular to the segment $[\varphi(s_1),\varphi(s_2)]$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I apologize that I cannot understand it because I have not studied topology yet. If you can give a geometric intuition to understand the answer, this will be useful for me. Thank you.

Comment: @زكرياحسناوي Yes, there is the following geometric intuition behind the fact. Pick two points $P_1$ and $P_1$ on the curve image $C$ placed at the largest distance (the rigorous proof of this fact is based on the compactness). For each $i\in\{1,2\}$ let $\ell_i$ be the straight line passing through the point $P_i$ and perpendicular to the segment $P_1P_2$. Then $\ell_i$ intersects the curve image $C$ only at the point $P_i$, because otherwise the distance between the points $P_1$ and $P_2$ is not maximal, a contradiction.

Comment: Moreover, if $C$ is smooth at the point $P_1$ then $\ell_i$ should be the tangent line to $C$ at $P_i$ (it seems that any other straight line passing through $P_i$ intersects $C$ in more than one point).

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

The convexity assumption can be removed. One only need to have a simple closed differentiable curve.

Call $\gamma : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ the curve. Assume that $\gamma$ is differentiable, that its derivative does not vanish anywhere, that $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)$ and $\gamma'(a)=\gamma'(b)$. Hence $\gamma$ can be extended into a $b-a$ - periodic differentiable map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The diameter of $\gamma([a,b]) := \sup\{|\gamma(t_2)-\gamma(t_1)| : (t_1,t_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2\}$ is not $0$ and achieved at some couple $(t_1,t_2)$. Therefore,
$$2 \langle \gamma(t_2)-\gamma(t_1),\gamma'(t_2) \rangle = \frac{d}{dt}\big(|\gamma(t)-\gamma(t_1)|^2\big)\Big|_{t=t_2} = 0,$$ so $\gamma'(t_2)$ is orthogonal to $\gamma(t_2)-\gamma(t_1)$. In the same way $\gamma'(t_1)$ is orthogonal to $\gamma(t_2)-\gamma(t_1)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I apologize that I cannot understand it because I have not studied topology yet. If you can give a geometric intuition to understand the answer, this will be useful for me. Thank you.